# Visual Studio forgets Resharper keyboard scheme

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

Visual Studio resets it's settings time to time. And first of it forgets all Resharper shortcuts binding.

It looks like:
I work 2 usual days, go to a kitchen for 10 minutes, come back and that's it - default visual studio keyboard mapping. Every time I have to reset keyboard from visual studio settings and then set ReSharper mapping once again.

I saw it a couple of times this way: I open visual studio with the black theme. And! it becomes white theme with default settings. Don't know why. Where is the reason? Perhaps it's not ReSharper's problem. But for me, it's most annoying part.

I do it last 5-6 years! Can anybody help? It was with Resharper 5 till last version and Visual Studio 2010 till 2017.
It's so annoying. I hate it so much.
No visual studio syncing is turned on.

Comment: What version of Resharper and Visual Studio are you using? Does anything else strange happen to your PC whilst you are in the kitchen? Does it also happen when you go to other rooms in the house? Do you have cats that walk over your keyboard whilst you are away?

Comment: @PiersMyers Resharper 2018.1, VS 15.6.7. It's different places, different works, different cats or no cats situations all years long. I edited my question.